# IE11 Developer Tools does not work

Tags: internet-explorer

I have installed IE11 (11.0.9600.17501) on my machine, but I can not use the Developer Tools. It shows nothing for almost all tabs, and for DOM Explorer tab it shows the below:

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It's not an answer but the F12 tools are currently broken on some machines due to the December patch Tuesday not being applied correctly (for unknown reasons). We're looking into the issue but don't have a fix for you to try out just yet. I'll post an answer when we do. 

(Disclosure: I work on the F12 team.)

Comment: @AndySterland Thanks for the information. I hope that the fix can be released soon. Off topic, the reason why I installed IE11 is because I encountered frequent crashes when using IE9 recently (I think since last week or early this week), and some people also say it is due to the December patch. So might be those issues are related as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Andy Sterland mentioned in the comment, this is due to the December patch not being applied correctly. Today I installed an update in Windows again, named Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3008923), and this update seems the one that resolves the issue.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45154&WT.mc_id=rss_security_updates

Comment: For whoever downloading this update and sees "update is not applicable to your computer" while running IE - try to close IE and start update again.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me at last!!!

Make sure you download a proper file. You need a patch for 64 bit system, not 32 bit. Microsoft site does not detect your system and allows you to download wrong file!

This is 32 bit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45134

This is 64 bit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45154

Comment: Both your links go to the 32 bit version.  I tried to fix it in an edit.  The real 64 bit version is available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=45154

Comment: Fixed your edit, you only changed the label, not the link related to the label. The posts Link is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Visual Studio installed? Looks like some people have seen this issue after updating Visual Studio.

Check here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f9089ae2-10d6-4e40-97d6-6a999c2f2fcc/update-3-error-jsplugin3005?forum=vssetup

If so, looks like re-installing the latest VS update could get you going again.

If you aren't a Visual Studio user, maybe try disabling IE11 and then run the system file checker (SFC.exe from a command prompt) and then re-enable IE11. Since you can't uninstall IE11, this is the next best thing to try. (reference - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318378)

Comment: I have Visual Studio but I'm not using that version nor do some updating of VS recently. The thing that I did is only installing IE11.