# IE11 Developer Tools is blank white/gray

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When I run F12 Developer Tools in my Windows Server 2012 R2's install of IE 11.0.9600.17498 (Update 11.0.15), I get a blank white area with grayed out buttons:

[image: IE11 with blank F12 Dev Tools]

(That white rectangle at the bottom of the image is F12 devtools)

I've discovered a number of other people with similar issues (e.g. [IE11 Developer Tools does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/853606/ie11-developer-tools-does-not-work)), but they're a bit different in that they have the "black stripe" above the tools and an error message.

I've tried running filesystem checks and updating all Windows Updates to no avail.

EDIT: I don't think this is a dupe, as I've installed the specified updates, and the issues persist.